# How we set value of pair in data grid combo box column in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I create data grid combo box column in wpf, now I want to set value of pairs in it.I want to display full value but selected value path is ID.

Comment: value of pairs ? what does it men ?

Comment: It's mean that selected value is M and Display value is Male and selected value M store in Database, after store refresh the datagrid and show Male

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Bind your itemssource to a collection of an object which has two properties. Id and whatever you want to call the other one. Gender maybe.
Genders are going to be completely static, so you could define that as a resource in a resourcedictionary.

Make SelectedValuePath Id
SelectedValueBinding whatever you're setting to ID.
DisplayMemberPath Gender, or whatever you want to call the longer string.

More information here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26347.wpf-combobox-binding-in-datagrid.aspx
and
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19493.wpf-best-combobox-tutorial-ever.aspx